# Update many-to-many relationship efficiently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I've 2 model classes.

```
public class Candidate
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
}
```

This creates me 3 tables.

- Candidates

  - Id  Name
  - 1   Tom
  - 2   John

---

- Skills

  - Id  Name
  - 1    C#
  - 2    MVC
  - 3    SQL
  - 4    nHibernate
  - 5    Java

    ---

I've made the association in the AUTOGENERATED table :

- CandidateSkills

  - CandidateId SkillId
  - 1             2
  - 1             3

---

Now I've want to update the skills for  **candidateId 1 i.e. Tom who wants to remove his SkillId : 2 i.e. MVC and add new SkillId : 4 & 5 i.e. nHibernate & Java respectively**.

I get the set of  **Ids**  from the form i.e.  **3, 4 & 5  & and the candidate Id : 1** , Since 2 is removed by the user.

My API is like this :

```
public Candidate Add(int candidateId, int[] skillIds)
{
    var model = dbContext.candidate.Find(candidateId);
}
```

---

How do I update the candidate record in an efficient way, making the least database calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With many-to-many associations in Entity Framework you can only work with objects, not with primitive Id values.

```
public void Add(int candidateId, int[] skillIds)
{
    var model = dbContext.candidate.Include(c => c.Skills)
                         .Single(candidateId => c.candidateId == candidateId);

    var skills = dbContext.Skills.Where(s => skillIds.Contains(s.Id)).ToArray();
    foreach (var skill in skills)
    {
        model.Skills.Add(skill);
    }

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

You must fetch the candidate with its skills loaded, hence the `Include`. The skills must be loaded for EF to be able to track changes to the collection.

If it's really a great deal for you to optimize performance you must create a junction class `CandidateSkill` class in your model, so you can add/delete associations without loading candidate or skill objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CandidateToSkill
{
    public Candidate Candidate{ get; set; }
    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
    public int CandidateID { get; set; }


    [Key,Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SkillID{ get; set; }

    public Skill Skill { get; set; }


}
```

You need also add this class as DbSet in your dbContext class

```
public class Candidate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CandidateToSkill> CandidateSkills{ get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CandidateToSkill> SkillCandidates{ get; set; }
}
```

and the controller code

```
public void Add(int candidateId, int[] skillIds)
{
    using (var db = new YourdbContext())
        {
            foreach (int skillID in skillIds )
            {
                 db.CandidateToSkill.Add(new CandidateToSkill(){skillID,candidateId});
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

}
```

in this sample u have only marking a candidates to add to our context (in your Link-table) and  Adding em to db with db.SaveChanges()

Answer (score 0):

You could just mark the entity state as modified and save the context.

```
public void UpdateCandidate(Candidate candidate)
{
   Context.Entry(candidate).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```